# Programmatically open image full-screen in Windows 10

Tags: windows, image, automation, windows-10, command-line-interface

I'm trying to programmatically open an image from a folder and have it completely fill the screen, and it seems the only way to have an image completely fill the screen is to click the Slideshow button in Windows Photo Viewer and pause the slideshow. However, in Windows 10 it isn't even possible to programmatically open an image (at least, not via the command line, using either Windows Photo Viewer or Photos), let alone paused in slideshow mode.

If not the command-line, are there any other good programmatic solutions for what I want to do?

Comment: Write a program to display the image in a fullscreen window. The apps that come with Windows are not part of the API.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks Raymond, I think it's fair to say you of all people would know the answer to this question best. :) Which API would I need to hook into for this and where would I find the documentation for it? Also, would I need to write it in C++ or are there other options?

Answer (score 0):

Hashim - You could quite easily write an app for this using open Lazarus.